# Microsoft Office for Mac 2011: add-on that can open Visio and Project files

Tags: macos, ms-office

I've been using OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5 and Office for Mac 2011. Is there any software or add-on that can be used to open Visio and Project files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about visio but for project theres

- [Moos](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33487/moos-project-viewer) - just a viewer
- [Project Libre](http://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/) - project management software (but can open ms project files)